# Altering a MySQL query to work in SQL Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a query that was originally written for MySQL that writes a timestamp to a record. The query adds 15 minutes to the timestamp, based on the time the query is run.

```
$query = $con->prepare("UPDATE TableName SET     
LockExpiryTime=ADDTIME(NOW(),'00:15:00'),LockKey=:lockkey
WHERE NOW() > LockExpiryTime AND formID = :formid");
$data = array('lockkey'=>$_SESSION['LockKey'],'formid'=>$_SESSION['formId']);
$query->execute($data);
```

I know that NOW() is not used in SQL Server, so I'm wondering how I can reconfigure this query to work in it and write the timestamp to a timestamp field. Or would datetime be better in this case?

EDIT: I should explain what this is used for. When the user logs into a form, a lock key and expiration time are generated. The lock lasts fifteen minutes. When the user logs out, both the key and expiry time are reset.

Comment: The equivalent of Now() in SQL Server is GETDate()

Comment: Thanks, that's half the battle won. Is there an MSSQL equivalent to ADDTIME?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this `DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, getdate())` in SQL Server,
instead of `ADDTIME(NOW(), '00:15:00')` which you used in MySQL.